# How can i make image scale on hover inside the container?

Tags: javascript, css

[image: scale image]

I want the image to scale but not the container.

```
    <div class="container">
     <img class="img" src="" />
   </div>
```

Comment: on img give hover

`img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}`

give transition to for smoothness. Try and let me know. I will put it up as answer then as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add max-width for the `container` and set `transform:scale` for the image when hovering and set `overflow:hidden` for the container so that the scaled image won't go out of the container . Also add `transition` for cool effects.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 300px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.container::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease all;
}
img {transition: .5s ease all; width: 100%; object-fit:cover;}
.container:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.container:hover::after {opacity: 0.2;}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
     <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" />
   </div>
```

Add pseudo element like `::before` or `::after` for the ovelay effect and display its visibility on hovering